# How to redirect HTTP requests to Azure Blob Storage base urls?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have a Blob Storage baseurl like this:
https://mycompany.blob.core.windows.net/myprod
.. which has several files and folders inside it.

Now, when at some point an app (not in our control) makes a HTTP request to the above URL, which now returns a **404 not found** (this is Blob Storage behavior; accessing the files inside the base url is fine).

And this causes things to blow up in our setup!

So, to workaround this, we want to **listen through webhooks** the HTTP request made to the baseurl above (only the baseurl, not when HTTP requests are made to files inside it) and return a **200** from an Azure Function.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Generally speaking, StackOverflow is not a place where the community writes code for you - it's understood that you have to try writing some code yourself first and then we can help you refine it or fix it.  With that said, what you're asking for is completely possible but anyone would need more requirements before even getting started - for example do you want C# or node.js, and is a 204/No Response not more appropriate?

Comment: @Graham - how is it "completely possible" to intercept calls made to a domain name managed by Azure, pointing directly to blob storage? It's not.

Comment: You'd have to use the Function as a proxy server, of course.

Comment: I posted an answer, regarding intercepting calls directed at blob storage. However, most of your question (aside from the intecept part) makes no sense (e.g. why you're getting 404's).

Comment: @Graham - you cannot intercept a call to `something.blob.core.windows.net` - you cannot put a proxy in between, unless you did that at the client's local network (which is like a man-in-the-middle attack). Aside from malicious intent (e.g. modifying local dns), what you're suggesting is not possible.

Comment: My production code proves you wrong.  Sorry.

Comment: Not going to argue with you, and you've proven nothing. But I've explained to the OP how Azure *actually* works. Totally possible to redirect *to* a blob via an app's URI. Not possible to intercept a call directly to a blob without trickery as I've explained. Not going to comment anymore. Feel free to check out my profile here - this is what I work on, for a living.

Comment: Well shiver my timbers and call me silly, **@Graham** could you post a gist of that interceptor code? We're all engineers here and naturally this is very relevant to our interests, not to mention it will also partially or completely answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot intercept calls pointing directly to blob storage. That DNS name (`yourname.blob.core.windows.net`) routes directly to Azure Blob Storage.

If you specifically need to intercept calls, then you need to route them to a dns name of your app (e.g. `yourname.azurewebsites.net` or `yourname.com` mapping to `yourname.azurewebsites.net`, if it's a web app). At this point, you could redirect to whatever you want (including blob storage URI's).

Note: Any blob URI you redirect to either needs to be public-accessible or have a Shared Access Signature (or policy) for your client app to get to it, otherwise a 404 will result.